# How to save a fixest class coefplot as a jpeg or pdf?

Tags: r, pdf, export, jpeg, fixest

I have a nice coefplot that plotting an object that I calculated with `feglm` command. Now I want to save it as an pdf and jpeg object that I could export somewhere else. I would also like to tinker with the width and height.

Thank you,

Comment: Can you provide the code you use to generate the plot? This would be helpful to provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You use pdf(), plot it, then dev.off(). For example:

```
est = feols(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width + Sepal.Length +
              Sepal.Width | Species, iris)

pdf("plot.pdf")
coefplot(est)
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to Patrick's answer, those are regular base-R graphs, so any regular export tool work.

FWIW the [fplot](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fplot/index.html)'s package contains dedicated tools to export graphs that may facilitate graph exportation.

The principle is the same:

```
library(fixest) ; library(fplot)

est = feols(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width + Sepal.Length +
              Sepal.Width | Species, iris)

pdf_fit("plot.pdf")
coefplot(est)
fit.off()
```

Instead of `pdf`/`dev.off`, here it's fplot's equivalent `pdf_fit`/`fit.off`.
What's the difference?

- you give the desired point size of the text in your graph in your target document (typically US letter or A4)
- you give the target width (or height) in your final document as a fraction of text size

You should end up with a graph for which the text is "garanteed" to have the specified point size *in your final document*.
After exportation, the exported graph is also displayed in RStudio's viewer, so you can check directly if you like it or not.

See more detailed explanations in the [dedicated vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fplot/vignettes/Exporting_graphs.html)